# Service to manage newsletters but allows per user database driven data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, subscription

If this is off-topic, I'd be glad to close the question. It is related to software development in that I'm looking to send out an email blast each week to subscribers for my service. The catch is, I need to put custom data in the blast such as, "You've done these things last week, here's what I'm going to recommend you do this week!". All of the data is determined by my application. The question is, do I have to build my own subscription management service in order to handle this level of granularity? I am not interested in doing that and would rather pay a mailing service to handle opt in/might opt, and I want them to handle all the mail infrastructure. I have to be able to supply the data / templates that are going out though.

Is there a service that's good for this these days?

Comment: Have you found a service that does this?